What prevents this QWidget from being repositioned?
I am working on a media player (spotify clone?) and want to recreate the "meatball" menu found on songs and like the way it floats freely next to the meatball button and remains there.
My initial thoughts were to use a dialog, however that doesn't seem similar to the way spotify implemented the menu, as it isn't a standalone window. I then thought to use a "sub-box" widget to hold all my song widgets, then have a button within the song widget to act as an anchor(?) to create the menu.
I have created a small mock-up in a separate file to try and get this to work and have so far gotten the button to create a widget using a custom signal.
    class subBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, widgets: list[QWidget]):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        for count, wi in enumerate(widgets):
            layout.addWidget(wi)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    @Slot()
    def addWid(self, item: testSong):
        # TODO
        '''
        We have the song object that is part of the overall layout.
        Now we can create the meatball menu, and slot it over the list of stuff?
        '''
        layout = self.layout()
        idx = layout.indexOf(item)
        if idx == -1:
            print("Not present.")
            return

        button: testSongButton = item.findChild(testSongButton)
        if button.findChild(testSongMeatball):
            print("Meatball spawned.")
            return
        

        item.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")

        meatball = testSongMeatball(button)
        meatball.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        meatball.show()

subBox is the centralWidget of mainWindow and contains a testSong widget written as:
class testSong(QWidget):
    meatballCreated = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballCreated")

    meatballDestroyed = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballDestroyed")

    def __init__(self, data={"name": "name", "album": "album"}):
        super().__init__()
        # song needs a label and a meatball?
        # Horizontal

        # init layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        label = QLabel(data['name'])
        album = QLabel(data['album'])

        meatball = testSongButton("Meatball menu")

        # connect clicked signal to relay into a meatballCreate signal, passing this widget
        # as a param
        meatball.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.meatballCreated.emit(self))  
        
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(album)
        layout.addWidget(meatball)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)

There is a lot of extra stuff to try to mimic my actual app but the main point is: testSong contains two labels and a button, which when clicked will "spawn" a meatball widget. subBox.addwid is a slot that receives a testSong widget and searches that widget for the button child and uses that button as the parent of the newly created meatball menu. I have tried using sizePolicy, sizeHint, updateGeometry and more to get the meatball widget to move around within the button, but I cannot get it to move.
 Here is how the window looks initially.
 And here (ugly background colors) is after clicking the button to spawn the menu. I have resized the window to show how QLabel and QPushButton's sizePolicy differ, and I have tried making meatball be the child of a QLabel to see if that would help but it doesn't. I was hoping to resize the meatball widget to be bigger than the button widget and then offset it somehow, but realise now this is probably a dumb way to do it.
I think I will instead try to make the meatball widget a child of subBox and use the geometry of the button to reimplement a resizeEvent() method of meatball, after looking around a bit. However I still would like to know why I am unable to move or resize the meatball widget as a child? Is there something I need to reimplement??
Any and all help would be welcome, and I hope I have formatted the question correctly and in an easy to read format.
EDIT: 16.11.24
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRect,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, Slot,
                            )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel,
                               QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                               QMainWindow, QApplication,
                               QSizePolicy)

class TestSong(QWidget):

    meatballCreated = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballCreated")
    meatballDestroyed = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballDestroyed")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        label = QLabel("Label")

        meatball = TestSongButton("Meatball button")

        # connect clicked signal to relay into a meatballCreate signal, passing this widget
        # as a param
        meatball.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.meatballCreated.emit(self))  
        
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(meatball)
    

class TestSongButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: purple")


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        return super().resizeEvent(event)
    
    def moveEvent(self, event):
        return super().moveEvent(event)
    

class testSongMeatball(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        text = QLabel("Meatball Menu")
        layout.addWidget(text)
        

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print("Meatball Resized!")  # this never prints
        return QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        print("Meatball Moved!")  # this never prints
        self.findPlace()
        return super().moveEvent(event)
        

    def findPlace(self):
        p: SubBox = self.parent()
        if p:
            # find song item and store its position
            item: TestSong = p.findChild(TestSong)
            item_pos = item.pos()

            # find button within song item and store its position
            button: TestSongButton = item.findChild(TestSongButton)
            button_pos = button.pos()

            # since item sits inside SubBox, the meatball will have the same geometry starting point (I think?)
            # So to find the button we need to add them
            x,y = item_pos.x(), item_pos.y()
            nx,ny, = button_pos.x(), button_pos.y()

            # Add co-ordinates to get button's top left corner
            meatball_pos = QPoint(x+nx,y+ny)

            # Create a QRect with the new position and size of meatball (self)
            meatball_geo = QRect(meatball_pos, self.size())
            self.setGeometry(meatball_geo)

    def sizePolicy(self):
        return QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(70,50)


class SubBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
        self.setLayout(layout)

    @Slot()
    def addWid(self, item: TestSong):
        layout = self.layout()
        idx = layout.indexOf(item)
        if idx == -1:
            print("Not present.")
            return
        
        # If meatball already exists
        if self.findChild(testSongMeatball):
            print("Meatball already present.")
            return
        
        # Create meatball widget
        meatball = testSongMeatball(self)  
        meatball.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        meatball.findPlace()  # find geometry
        meatball.show()  # show meatball

        print("Meatball spawned")
        


class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        window_widget = QWidget()
        window_layout = QVBoxLayout(window_widget)

        # Give total layout a label
        window_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Window"))
        
        # Create sub-box
        sub = SubBox()

        window_layout.addWidget(sub)

        test_widget = TestSong()

        sub.layout().addWidget(test_widget)
        
        test_widget.meatballCreated.connect(
            lambda item: sub.addWid(item))
        
        
        # set window as central
        self.setCentralWidget(window_widget)


        print(self.layout())
        
def main():
    # Create app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



"I have tried using sizePolicy, sizeHint, updateGeometry and more to get the meatball widget to move around within the button": you are not showing how you're actually trying to move that button, so we cannot really tell you why you can't move it. In any case, a widget can only draw within its geometry, and its children can only be shown within the geometry of their parent: even if you manually set the geometry of a child outside the parent's boundaries, you will still only see what's within the parent's bounding rectangle: you cannot show a child outside of its parent.

Thanks for your reply. I tried: reimplementing sizePolicy on the child widget with “Ignored, Maximum, ‘Fixed’, then reimplementing sizeHint with differing sizes from 10,20 to 1000,10000 just to see if it would change anything. Your last point is the answer I’m looking for, but I would like to read more into why just so I can understand which part of the code actually enforces this

The size policy only has effect on widgets that are managed by a layout, so it would be pointless in your case because that menu would be a "free" widget. Overriding sizeHint() should be enough, but as said you didn't show us the code for that testSongMeatball class, so we cannot tell you why it didn't work (so, please consider providing a more comprehensive [mre]). The reason for which a child cannot be shown outside of the parent is due to the widget architecture, which is common in almost any UI framework: each parent acts as a "viewport" for its children, similarly to a window (and »

» with "window" I mean both computer windows and physical windows in buildings), you can only see what's within the window boundary, not outside of it. This is explained in various places of the docs, but the Qt object tree overview tells it explicitly: "A child [...] is displayed in its parent's coordinate system and is graphically clipped by its parent's boundaries". If you want to display widget B outside of widget A, then you cannot make B a child of A, but, at the very least, a child of A's parent, possibly its top level window.

Thanks for the update, now it's fine. You can remove all your replies about posting the MRE.

Your first attempt is ineffective, because the visibility of children is always restricted by the geometry of their parent, which acts as a viewport (similarly to a physical window): you cannot show a child outside the bounding rect of the parent widget.
If you want to do the above, you need to make the widget a child of the parent in which it can be fully shown, which in cases like this usually means the top level widget (the "window").
Yet, since the widget is not managed by a layout, you need to properly resize it, which cannot just rely on the widget's size().
All new widgets have a default size, unless an explicit minimum or maximum (or fixed) size is set.
When created without a parent, that size is 640x480, but when created with
a parent, it is 100x30, which is exactly the size you see, and that's also because you're calling self.size() to set the new geometry.
Since the widget is not managed by a layout, it's up to you to resize it to the required dimensions. You've already overridden sizeHint(), so the solution is relatively simple:
    meatball_geo = QRect(meatball_pos, self.sizeHint())
    self.setGeometry(meatball_geo)

A conceptually identical alternative is to rely on adjustSize(), which automatically resizes the widget based on its sizeHint() (if it's valid): so, just call move(), followed by adjustSize().
    self.move(meatball_pos)
    self.adjustSize()

Note that the above won't solve two important aspects:

if the "popup" is large enough, it may not be shown in full because the new position may make it "overflow" outside of the window margins;
if the window is resized while the popup is visible, its geometry would become inconsistent, since it probably won't be aligned anymore with the supposed widget, or it can even become completely invisible;

The only appropriate way to fix those issues is by making the popup a child of the top level window, and install an event filter on that window, which will then check for Resize events and eventually update the popup geometry, but the function that sets that geometry must also ensure that the popup rectangle is still within the window bounding rect.
Finally, sizePolicy is a property, trying to override its function is not only useless, but quite inappropriate.
The only way to set the size policy of a widget is by properly calling setSizePolicy(). Remember that only functions labeled as "virtual" in the official C++ docs can be overridden.

OK thank you. I began to think it was because of the lack of layout management by choosing not to install it on SubBox's layout, however I don't rightly know how layout's actually go about managing stuff. Your second to last paragraph is a great starting point; to ensure it is within the bounding rect, which is what I assume layout managers do, should I do something like: Get top right of Meatball, then check if its width/height added to the coords exceeds the total window size?

If you want to learn more about how layout management works, start by patiently reading the whole documentation, then consider both experimenting on your own (starting with standard widgets), and using Qt Designer in order to have a live playground to test various aspects (including the various combinations of size policies). About the correct positioning, the easiest way is to create a rect (based on the size hint) for the possible geometry, position it where you want it, and then check its sides against the parent's rect(): eg: if the widget rect's right()

» is beyond the right() of the parent rect, then use setRight() with that. Then do the same for all the other sides, and finally call setGeometry() on the widget. Note that, for obvious reasons, the top and left of the parent rect will always be 0 (because rect() is in local coordinates, while geometry() is in parent coordinates).
